# The Sample Project I can examine OOP in Details

Tags: c#, types, design-patterns

I've working on Interfaces and Class and Structs types and I really wanna learn advanced yet simple patterns to understand those types correctly and use them efficiently.

Is there any you know ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's always Enterprise FizzBuzz.

http://wolfbyte-net.blogspot.com/2007/09/if-something-is-worth-doing.html

Seriously, I've referred to this project quite a few times for ideas on how to set things up well.

Comment: I am gonna check it out.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This may be overkill, and a little too much code, but you could take a look at Microsoft's Enterprise Library (EntLib).  The source is available to download.  Its by the patterns and practices team, and most certainly uses numerous oop principals.

It includes application blocks for inclusion in your projects such as Caching, Cryptography, Data Access, Exception Handling, Logging, Policy Injection, Security, Validation, and Unity.

[EntLib Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512464.aspx)

Comment: Yeah,it's really overkill for some one like me junior developer but thanks for help.